# A computer architecture joke

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, gpu, operating-system

**Background**

Some months ago, I watched a Youtube video posted by the channel **Numberphile**. The video was on famous world mathematician Terence Tao, and in the video, he seemed to be struggling with speech. I don't know if he has any speech impediments or a stutter, but there were several comments under the video stating that it was because his brain moves too fast for his mouth to catch up. However this one in particular caught my eye:

> His brain 240 FPS, his mouth 60 hz

to which I responded:

> FPS and hz aren’t comparable mate

Now, it is my understanding, in my experience taking computer architecture courses at university, that Hertz are cycles per second, and fps frames rendered per second, aren't directly comparable units. And in fact, for the joke to have been more effective in my opinion the units in the joke should've been reversed (although exaggerated) to be:

> His Brain 240 ghz, his mouth 60fps

as I assume the initial joke was inferring that Tao's brain is a fast cpu while his mouth is slow renderer. I got some serious insults and backlash my way as a result of making this comment, so much that I contemplated the validity of my university computer science education.

So if there's any experts out there on this topic, can you please confirm or deny if the initial joke was well stated, and makes sense from a computer architecture point of view, and if I am in fact the idiot on youtube. The link to the video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXJ-zpJeY3E&t=84s&ab_channel=Numberphile and the joke is the second comment. Thanks, I just want to be educated lol.

Comment: FPS and Hz can be directly compared if these Hz indicate the frequency of the frames. But CPU frequency is the frequency of its clock and simplistically indicating the frequency of instruction processing. So even though both are frequencies, these are frequencies of apples and oranges. The joke validity and its reception is an opinionated thing and is not to be discussed here.

Comment: You are overthinking this by about 5 paragraphs. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flogging_a_dead_horse

Comment: @crasic you're right. But does it make sense?

Comment: Hz and fps are both cyclical rates, however hz is a dimensionless rate (s^-1) but fps is in units of frames (fs^-1).  Horse is now completely dead.

Comment: @williamcodes: FPS = frames (pictures) per second generated by the graphics card.  Hertz = refresh rate (pictures per second) shown on a monitor.  It matches, and makes perfect sense.  Graphics cards are fully capable of rendering more pictures per second than the hardware of the monitor can display.  Look up the term "tearing" in relation to graphics cards and monitors.

Comment: `I just want to be educated` ... i think that you are asking for the wrong education ... you should really be asking if it is rude to joke about a person's speech pattern ... please find some other way to joke about FPS and Hz

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a pointless argument of semantics, on an off-topic subject matter, beginning from a mistaken premise.

Comment: Sounds like you jumped with an ill-thought-through smart-ass comment and were rightly called on it.

Comment: Rendering a frame is a type of cycle. <- it's literally that simple. You can call a refresh rate either Hz or FPS if you want. Only one of those is an SI unit.

Comment: @SiHa chill out mate.

Comment: I'm quite chilled thanks, "mate". Thanks for caring though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hz and fps are both cyclical rates, however hz is a ***rate*** (\$\large\frac{1}{s}\$) and fps is in units of frames (\$\large\frac{f}{s}\$), i.e. a symbol rate that can be expressed as bps.

Sometimes a measure or count of (system clock) cycles is implied by hertz, especially in informal discussion such as a joke.

Comment: Hertz is not dimensionless, as you said the dimensions are 1/s.

Comment: Also frames are a countable thing, not a measurement, so they're dimensionless and fps also has units of 1/s.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate - *Frame rate may also be called the frame frequency, and be expressed in hertz.*

Comment: @ElliotAnderson I believe I have addressed both of your comments in my edit, please review

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I believe the question was asked from an architectural pov, of course in a domain specific way there are other interpretations of frame rate possible.

Comment: @Hearth I believe your comment was addressed in my recent edit.

Comment: @crasic No, frames are still a countable, and thus dimensionless, thing.

Comment: @Hearth I'm not so certain it has been well enough defined as to so definitively exclude other interpretations.